# PHP to Console Commands are Not Functioning as Expected

Tags: php, terminal

I am currently working on a PHP script which sends commands to the terminal to be executed until an error occurs, or the execution is successful and then returns the results to a webpage. The problem I am running into is that certain terminal commands I am attempting to execute are successful when I input them manually, however; aren't functioning as expected when they are executed by the PHP script:

ex. In my php script I use:

```
$copy = popen('./a.out > temp.txt', 'r');
pclose($copy);
```

This pipes the output of a.out to temp.txt successfully when temp.txt exist, but doesn't when temp.txt doesn't exist.

Manually inputting: `./a.out > temp.txt` creates temp.txt and pipes the output as expected.

I have changed the read/write permissions and tried giving full permissions to no avail. Any ideas?